# Modify the existing canonical link in header

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, canonical-link

I am using Joomla 2.5 and I want to change the canonical link in the header.
I do this in category view (components/com_content/category/tmpl/default.php)

```
$url        = JURI::root();
$sch        = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME);
$server     = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
$canonical  = $this->escape($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);    
$document->addCustomTag('<link rel="canonical" href="'.$sch.'://'.$server.$canonical.'"/>');
```

It prints the right canonical, but it also leaves the old canonical link there so that I have 2 canonical links in the header.

How can I change or delete the old canonical link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want to do instead is something like the following:

```
$doc_data = $document->getHeadData();
$url        = JURI::root();
$sch        = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME);
$server     = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
$canonical  = $this->escape($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
$newtag     = '<link rel="canonical" href="'.$sch.'://'.$server.$canonical.'"/>'

$replaced = false;
foreach ($doc_data['custom'] as $key=>$c) {
    if (strpos($c, 'rel="canonical"')!==FALSE) {
        $doc_data['custom'][$key] = $newtag;
        $replaced = true;
    }
}
if (!$replaced) {
    $doc_data['custom'][] = $newtag;
}

$document->setHeadData($doc_data);
```

This will grab all of the current head data from the document, including the canonical link that you want to replace. It will search through the custom set (where I'm guessing this will be) and if it finds it, replace it with yours. If it doesn't find it, then it tacks it on at the end. Just in case.

Potential problems with this that I can see right away:

1. If the tag contained `rel='canonical'` with single quotes it would not be found, so you may have to adjust that.
2. The tag may have been placed in a different section of what I've termed `$doc_data`. You may want to do a `var_dump($doc_data};` to confirm the location of the variable in this array.

Comment: thank you, i was thinking it is some joomla functia that update/remove a specific header link. i will use your code ti`ll i find a better solution if is one :)  thank you!

Comment: hello, i have no canonical in $doc_data. i printed each array from $doc_data including $doc_data['custom'] which is empty

Comment: What is likely happening here then is that the second canonical link is being added after this point. The likely action is happening as part of your template. If it is ok to change this site wide instead of just for the category pages, you may want to shift all of this code to the index.php file of your template. 

At the very least, you would want to grab the `$doc_data` once in this file and see what is all there.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the following to work for me with Joomla! 3.2.1.  You can directly modify the

```
$_links
```

variable in the JHtmlDocument object.

I'm doing a subset of the following in a particular view of my component because the URL that Joomla! is coming up with is not correct.

Hope this helps.

```
    $document = JFactory::getDocument();
    foreach($document->_links as $key=> $value)
    {
        if(is_array($value))
        {
            if(array_key_exists('relation', $value))
            {
                if($value['relation'] == 'canonical')
                {                       
                    // we found the document link that contains the canonical url
                    // change it!
                    $canonicalUrl = 'http://www.something.com/index.php/component/my-component-name-here/?view=viewNameHere&amp;parameterNameHere=parameterValueUsedInTheViewRightNow

                    $document->_links[$canonicalUrl] = $value;
                    unset($document->_links[$key]);
                    break;                      
                }
            }
        }
    }
```